# why I can't login to cPanel, shows error Maximum Users Exceeded?

Tags: cpanel, webserver, authentication, whm, whmcs

When I try to login to cPanel,

it shows an error **Maximum Users Exceeded**. please see the error message below. I didn't do any changes to server. this appears very suddenly. how can I fix this? I searched for google on this error but couldn't find anything helpful.

[image]

Comment: Because your hosting service likely has a limited version of cpanel and has oversold shared hosting.  The new cpanel business model means hosts pay per account rather than per server.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. it's hosted in aws I think. would that be the problem?

Comment: You need to speak to your hosting provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that the cPanel license has been suspended because the server has too many users.

You can find out what kind of license you have by putting your server's IP into the following form:
https://verify.cpanel.net/app/verify

If you pay cPanel directly for your license, reach out to cPanel customer support for assistance with adding users to your license.

If you are paying a different company for your cPanel license, reach out to the customer support for that company.

The company that you need to talk to will usually be listed on the verification page I linked to above.

Comment: This was the exact thing happened. we used a third party for this and although we did our payment on time, they didn't. had to talk to them and after a heated argument, they agreed that problem was in their end. so we ended everything with them after that